# matching required array element with another array elements in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to match one array single column into another and print those lines. But it's coming as blank. Dont know where its going wrong. The individual element is getting printed...
Looking for some help. The code is as below;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use File::Find;

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define file names and its location
my $input = $ARGV[0];       # requires input raw DS8K PU file

############################################################################################
# Section to read config file and extract volumes of user inserted volumegroup
############################################################################################
my $input_PU_config = $ARGV[1];   # requires input config file

my @vg_vol_id;    # defining variable for config file
my @interval_data = ('start_time','length');

print "\nEnter the volume group number you need to work upon: ";    # I insert number as 8 and it greps "V8" required line from the config file
chomp (my $vol_grp_number = <STDIN>);

open (CONFIG_INFILE,"$input_PU_config_file") or die "Could not open: $!";
while (<CONFIG_INFILE>)
    {
     if (/ FB 512 / && (/ V$vol_grp_number,/ || /,V$vol_grp_number / || / V$vol_grp_number /))  ## If device is part of multiple VG
        {
         my @volume_id = split(/\s+/,$_);
         push @vg_vol_id, "0x$volume_id[1]";
         #print "0x$volume_id[1]\n";
        }
    }
unshift @vg_vol_id,@interval_data;
#print "@vg_vol_id\n";
close (CONFIG_INFILE);
############################################################################################
# Grab the only vols stats for different intervals and put it in a file
open (INFILE,"$input_file") or die "Could not open: $!";
open (OUTFILE,">$output_file") or die "Could not open: $!";
while (<INFILE>)
    {
     if (/^volume stats/ .. /^$/)
        {
         print (OUTFILE "$_");
        }
    }
close (INFILE);
close (OUTFILE);
###############################################################################################
# the parsed file is stored as @PU_file array element
open (PARSED_PU_FILE,"$output_file") or die "Could not open parsed file: $!";
my @PU_file = <PARSED_PU_FILE>;
###############################################################################################
foreach my $PU_file_line (@PU_file)
    {
            #chomp ($PU_file_line);
            #print "$line\n";
            foreach my $line (@vg_vol_id)
                    {
                            chomp ($line);
                            #print "$line\n";
                            if ( $line =~ m/^$PU_file_line/)
                            {
                                    print "$PU_file_line\n";
                            }
                    }
                    #print "======================\n";
    }
close (PARSED_PU_FILE);
```

The input.txt file looks as below

```
unwanted lines
unwanted lines
unwanted lines
unwanted lines

volume stats
start_time  1
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,1,2,3,4
0x00b,11,12,13,14
0x00c,21,22,23,24

unwanted lines
unwanted lines
unwanted lines

volume stats
start_time  2
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,31,32,33,34
0x00b,41,42,43,44
0x00c,51,52,53,54

unwanted lines
unwanted lines
unwanted lines

volume stats
start_time  3
length      2
--------
ID
0x00a,61,62,63,64
0x00b,71,72,73,74
0x00c,81,82,83,84

unwanted lines
unwanted lines
unwanted lines
```

The config_input.txt file looks as below;

```
unwanted lines
unwanted lines
EP0Vol1000   00a Online   Normal    Normal      2107-900  FB 512   P0      Standard      DS        68.0           -    142606336 V4,V9            142606336 rotateexts PG0     RG0
EP0Vol1000   00b Online   Normal    Normal      2107-900  FB 512   P0      Standard      DS        68.0           -    142606336 V4,V8            142606336 rotateexts PG0     RG0
EP0Vol1001   00c Online   Normal    Normal      2107-900  FB 512   P0      Standard      DS        68.0           -    142606336 V4,V8            142606336 rotateexts PG0     RG0
EP0Vol1001   00d Online   Normal    Normal      2107-900  FB 512   P0      Standard      DS        68.0           -    142606336 V4,V10            142606336 rotateexts PG0     RG0
unwanted lines
unwanted lines
```

The output is coming blank.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: The script use posted won't even compile. Post a real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition at the end of your script from

```
$line =~ m/^$PU_file_line/
```

to

```
$PU_file_line =~ /^$line/
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks Jira. I am now working on blank space. But, didn't know I make such a silly mistake.